# How to manage .NET Master Pages in Dreamweaver CS4?

Tags: .net, adobe, master-pages, dreamweaver

Has anybody figured out how to make .aspx pages render the Master Page visuals in Dreamweaver design mode?

Comment: One possible solution to this was mentioned on another thread at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278979/master-in-dreamweaver-solution

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no solution at this point in time besides having them open the page in a browser and hitting refresh.

I've explained to my designer that this is not much different than when they slice up images in Photoshop, but with code.  So he keeps a page template that's essentially the master page without being a master page and does his work in there before pasting it to its final destination.  Not a big deal.