# .master in DreamWeaver solution?

Tags: visual-studio, dreamweaver

I have both dreamweaver CS5.5 and Visual Studio Ultimate 2010. Both programs I love, but I really want a way to complete all of my front end coding in Dreamweaver, and then work with the database in VS.Net.

I have been completing this by making all of the pages in VS.Net, and then clicking 'open with' Dreamweaver afterwards. Although each time I open the .master file with Dreamweaver it collapses into blank coding, propbably because it doesn't recognise it. I have researched this before,and tried to solve the problem by adding content to the documentType folder but nothing has happened. I really need some support in Dreamweaver because I am alsways changing the design of my pages, and each page uses a materpage file.

The other problem is the masterpage uses .swf files and javascript alot, which is a pain to use in VS.Net, as the code hinting doesn't work properly.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: You have posted just like a novel that is indeed difficult to understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: How do you make dreamweaver understand .master files?

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested it yet, but take a look at this: http://alexle.net/archives/119

> - Go to **[Your_Drive_Here]:\Program Files\Macromedia\Dreamweaver MX 2004\Configuration**
> - Open the file **Extensions.txt** and add your custom extensions to the list.
>     ...
> - Go to the **DocumentTypes** folder (still in the same path), edit the file **MMDocumentTypes.xml**\ (fullpath: [Your_Drive_Here]:\Program Files\Macromedia\Dreamweaver MX 2004\Configuration**DocumentTypes\MMDocumentTypes.xml**) with a Text Editor (i.e. Notepad or Notepad++). It’s not advisible to edit this particular xml file with Dreamweaver as the software may go crazy as it’s being used to edit itself.
> - Go to l**ine 67**, add the THTML extesion to the **winfileextension** and **macfileextensionlist** attributes. Here is the code exerpt

This instructions are for Dreamweaver MX 2004, but may work changing `Macromedia\Dreamweaver MX 2004` for `Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5` (I don't have CS5.5, but assuming this had not changed until CS4 (my version), it will be there.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have already tried this before I posted the comment, and it didn't work for my CS5.5 version of dreamweaver. I tried it again just then and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I know that this is an old post but I've still encountered this problem and I've found the fix. The MMDocumentTypes folder is also in `%appdata%\Adobe\DreamweaverCC\ ` then search for `MMDocumentTypes.xml` and you will find the copy it really listens to. Adding master as describe above to this file fixed it for me.

Comment: @rtpHarry Great! Thank you for telling us how to fix this. Would you mind to post this as an answer so I can vote for it and the question author can mark it as the solution?